# iOS project compilation

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

I am working on a project accessing web service. I found a project

http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/PromoTest.zip

The above code include JSON library [project setting compiler = LLVM 4.2]
And I tried to use partial code of that project in my project.
So I copied the JSON library into my project [my project uses Apple LLVM 3.1]
and then some error show up
eg.

```
SBJsonStreamWriterState **states;

//error:Pointer to non-const type "SBJsonStreamWriterState *" with no explicit ownership
```

I have tried using compiler flags -fno-objc-arc, no good.
I wonder if its a ARC problem? if it is, then why above compiler flag wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it by deleting SBJson Library. I found Apple already written a json library.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling ARC at the target level like shown in the attached picture:

[image]