# SBjsonstreamparser and SBJsonstreamwriter pointer to non-const type ... with no explicit owner ship

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using a framework for payment in iOS. It makes use of `SBJsonStreamWriter` and `SBJsonStreamParser` classes. My project is ARC enabled. ARC throws an error in a couple of variables: Pointer to a non-const type ... with no explicit ownership.

these are the vars:

```
SBJsonStreamWriterState **states;
@property(readonly) NSObject *states;

SBJsonStreamParserState **states;
@property (readonly) SBJsonStreamParserState **states;
```

Is there anything I can do to safely adjust these variables?
I am pretty new with this kind of material.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Disable ARC for these part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091059/ios-project-compilation

Comment: problem is, this Framework is a 'static library' i guess, and my project is fully ARC supported.

Comment: I only see the header files from SBJsonparser.. It's al defined in a name.framework in my project

Comment: would it be possible just to change these variables?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working by just adding __strong parameters:

In the header files, i've changed these:

```
SBJsonStreamWriterState **states;
@property(readonly) NSObject *states;

SBJsonStreamParserState **states;
@property (readonly) SBJsonStreamParserState **states;
```

To:

```
__strong SBJsonStreamWriterState **states;
@property(readonly) __strong NSObject *states;

__strong SBJsonStreamParserState **states;
@property (readonly) __strong SBJsonStreamParserState **states;
```